# Factors sieve optimization

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, primes, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I've written a more powerful version of the Sieve of Eratosthenes, this Sieve returns the number of factors of all the numbers below the `limit`.Sadly the running time is \$O(n^2)\$, so it is much slower than the ordinary sieve. Can you suggest a way to improve and optimize it?

```
import doctest

def factors_sieve(limit):
    """
    Returns the number of factors of all the numbers below the limit.
    For better convenience use list(enumerate(factors_sieve(limit)))

    >>> list(enumerate(factors_sieve(9)))
    [(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 2), (4, 3), (5, 2), (6, 4), (7, 2), (8, 4)]
    >>> factors_sieve(100000).count(2) # How many prime numbers below 100000?
    9592
    """
    sieve = [2]*limit
    sieve[0],sieve[1] = 0,1
    for number,number_of_divisors in enumerate(sieve):
        if number >= 2:
            for multiple in range(number*2, len(sieve), number):
                sieve[multiple] += 1

    return sieve

if __name__ == "__main__":
    doctest.testmod()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The running time is not \$ O(n^2) \$. It is \$ O(n \log n) \$. Why?
$$ T(n) = O \bigg( { n - 2 · 2 \over 2 } + { n - 2 · 3 \over 3 } + \dotsb + { n - 2 · { n \over 2 } \over { n \over 2 }} \bigg) = O(n \log n). $$ This is very similar to the sum of a harmonic series. So it is pretty good in terms of time complexity.

It is possible to optimize the code a little bit:

```
divisors_count = [2] * limit
divisors_count[0], divisors_count[1] = 0, 1
min_divisor = 2
max_divisor = len(divisors_count) // 2
for divisor in range(min_divisor, max_divisor + 1):
    for multiple in range(divisor * 2, len(divisors_count), divisor):
        divisors_count[multiple] += 1
return divisors_count
```

I changed the loop over the enumerated list to a loop over a range of divisors and removed the `if` statement inside the loop's body. In my opinion, it also makes the logic more clear because we do not need a list itself in the outer loop. It is also sufficient to iterate only up to `len(sieve) // 2`, because otherwise `range(number * 2, len(sieve), number)` is empty.

I also gave the variables more meaningful names: `divisor` instead of `number` and so on to make the code easier to understand (but the initial version is rather clear, too, in my opinion).

But either way, this code shows a good scalability: it runs for about 1.8–1.9 seconds with my optimizations, and 2.1–2.2 seconds without them, for `limit = 10 ** 6`.

Comment: Thanks for the complexity analysis, as soon as I saw two nested loops I thought it were O(N^2), but I didn't realize that the second loop was smaller, thanks! On a side note, isn't `len(divisors_count)` always equal to `limit`?

Comment: @Caridorc Yes, `limit == len(divisors_count)`.